# How to programmatically back up the table with the generated identity column?

Tags: c#, .net-core, hana

I have to take SAP HANA table backups programmatically using .NET Core. I am using `Sap.Data.Hana` package with `HanaBulkCopy` class.

I programmatically create the target table with generated identity column, as I cannot alter it later.

For the source tables with generated identity column, `HanaBulkCopy` class ignores the provided identity values and generates those in target.

When try to run a manual insert query, I got following error:

> INSERT, UPDATE and UPSERT are disallowed on the generated field: cannot inser into generated identity column field ID.

I tried to run this query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MYTABLE OFF;
```

before insert, but getting following error:

> SQL syntax error: incorrect syntax near "IDENTITY_INSERT": line 1...

Please note that I have constraints so I need to insert the IDs of the source to target as it is. And I need to have the auto generated identity behavior in the target as well.

Does anyone know how to get around this?